# problemas con la monetización en Android

Tags: java, android, admob

Hola a todxs tengo un problema con la monetizacion con admob
en el archivo Manifest tengo que agregar esto:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy
"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Mi problema esta aqui
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" que se supone que tengo que poner aqui? en la web oficial no lo dejan muy claro https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=es-419#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

alguna gente me ha dicho que tengo que poner android:name="com.mipackage.nombremiApp" pero al hacerlo craseah.
Alguien me puede ayudar.Un saludo.

Gracias por tu respuesta,es de agradecer.Ya había echo todo eso pero mi duda esta en el:

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
```

No tengo que modificar el android:name verdad?Solo el android:value como muestras en el ejemplo.No sé si me estoy explicando bien ...
el android:name debe quedar tal cual lo muestra la pagina de Google(igual a tu ejemplo) pero el android:value debo introducir mi idd de aplicación.Esto es asi?

Comment: android:value= debe tener el valor de un Ad Unit, primero debes crear la app https://apps.admob.com/  y luego dentro de esta app creas un Ad Unit, obtienes el código y lo configuras en tu AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Debes inicialmente que crear una App en https://apps.admob.com/ y obtener el Ad Unit que es un bloque de anuncios asociados a esta aplicación, eso es lo que indica la documentación.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431?hl=es-419

**Encontrar un ID de aplicación**

- Inicie sesión en su cuenta de AdMob en https://apps.admob.com.
- Haz clic en la opción Aplicaciones, situada en la barra lateral.
- Haz clic en Todas las aplicaciones.
- Haz clic en el icono [image: jorgesys admob 1] Copiar situado en la columna ID de la aplicación para copiar el ID de una aplicación.

**Encontrar un ID de bloque de anuncios**

- Inicie sesión en su cuenta de AdMob en https://apps.admob.com.
- Haz clic en la opción Aplicaciones, situada en la barra lateral.
- Haz clic en el nombre de la aplicación asociada al bloque de anuncios. Nota: - Si no aparece en la lista de aplicaciones recientes, haz clic en Ver todas las aplicaciones. Luego, haz clic en el nombre de la aplicación.
- Haz clic en la opción Bloques de anuncios, situada en la barra lateral.
- Haz clic en el icono [image: jorgesys admob 2] Copiar situado en la columna ID del bloque de anuncios para copiar el ID de un bloque de anuncios.

Cuando crees la app, puedes agregar un Ad Unit que sería el que configurarías en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-618245221480xxxxxx752511027
"/>
```